# Clarifications regarding "Subscription reports version update" for In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, skproduct

Today my client shared the below message and asked me if should I update something on the code side regarding In-App purchases. He got this email from Apple.

> "We’re reaching out to let you know that, starting March 1, 2023,
> subscription reports version 1.2 will no longer be available. If you
> automatically download subscription reports using the App Store
> Connect API or Reporter, please update your query parameter to version
> 1.3 if you haven’t already done so.Version 1.3 builds on version 1.2, and includes additional data to help you understand subscription offer
> code redemptions. With version 1.3, you’ll have access to the number
> of active subscribers using your offer codes and the number of offer
> code redemptions for your service. You can also find out if
> subscribers convert to paid renewal when the offer period ends.To
> learn how to specify a version when downloading reports, visit
> Download Sales and Trends Reports for the App Store Connect API or the
> Reporter User Guide for Reporter."

I didn't use any App Store Connect API to download subscription reports. But I used "Receipt Validation" after all successful purchases by calling API directly from Apple.

```
var verifyReceiptURL: String {
    #if LIVE_URL
    return "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    #else
    return "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    #endif
}

func receiptValidation(iapReceiptValidationFrom: IAPReceiptValidationFrom, completion: @escaping(_ isPurchaseSchemeActive: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
//Receipt validation code will be here
}
```

Should I be concerned about this and need to change anything on the code side?

Comment: This is nothing to do with receipt validation.  It is the subscription reports API that you can use to get subscription data; renewals, levels etc for reporting

Comment: @Paulw11 My thought was the same. It is related to subscription reports via App Store Connect API. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Do we need any updates or migration for App Store Connect API?